# get all list movieID in IMDbPY

Tags: python, imdbpy

I want get all movieID in list from IMDbPY. I want to get analyze most popular genre, actor etc in a given year. For example in 2014 find popular film, popular actor, genre etc with scikit-learn or other library. How to get list of movieID?

Comment: did you test IMDbPY?

Comment: try movieLens, they got a good list of movie to start with.
pick the ml-latest csv

Comment: no i don't test IMDbPY, i want find popular film, actor, genre e.t.c in years on python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this link http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ and download the ml-latest-small.zip

It will give you a list of 33k movies, with a link to the imdb id as an int. (advice: imdb use id starting with two tt and a fix number of number so you have to complete the id given by movie lens but it's no big deal)
Then you can query omdb with this id and get all information available from omdb or do some web scraping on imdb website (omdb is faster but has less information).

I can forward you some database I made out of tmdb, imdb, omdb and ml-latest if you want.

Comment: @GoldGshok can you validate the answer if you use this solution? Thanks !

Comment: If you want to try and find more recent movies, in general, the id of imdb in only incremented so the higher one would be the most recent one, but it isn't always true unfortunately

Comment: Is there still no option to this? I hope to build a graph database which consists of the movies, actors, directors and so on. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems IMDbPY is not supported yet to get all list,
If you are not dependent on this then

This might helps you

**Usage**

Send all data requests to:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?

Poster API requests:

http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&

**Example:**

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=zootopia&y=2016&plot=full&r=json

**Response:**

```
 {
Title: "Zootopia",
Year: "2016",
Rated: "PG",
Released: "04 Mar 2016",
Runtime: "108 min",
Genre: "Animation, Action, Adventure",
Director: "Byron Howard, Rich Moore, Jared Bush",
Writer: "Byron Howard (story), Jared Bush (story), Rich Moore (story), Josie Trinidad (story), Jim Reardon (story), Phil Johnston (story), Jennifer Lee (story), Jared Bush (screenplay), Phil Johnston (screenplay), Dan Fogelman (additional story material)",
Actors: "Ginnifer Goodwin, Jason Bateman, Idris Elba, Jenny Slate",
Plot: "From the largest elephant to the smallest shrew, the city of Zootopia is a mammal metropolis where various animals live and thrive. When Judy Hopps becomes the first rabbit to join the police force, she quickly learns how tough it is to enforce the law. Determined to prove herself, Judy jumps at the opportunity to solve a mysterious case. Unfortunately, that means working with Nick Wilde, a wily fox who makes her job even harder.",
Language: "English, Norwegian",
Country: "USA",
Awards: "N/A",
Poster: "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOTMyMjEyNzIzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjU0NzE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
Metascore: "78",
imdbRating: "8.4",
imdbVotes: "42,414",
imdbID: "tt2948356",
Type: "movie",
Response: "True"
}
```

Comment: It's not what he asked, he wants a list of all id

Comment: ofc there is, with movie lens (but you can't get all the movie in IMDB without some effort indeed)

Comment: it's work, but i find all_ID or base in file, because i want work in python and analize big data about films.

Comment: omdb is going private...FYI